# nvm use giving Execution of the Windows Script Host Failed error

Tags: cmd, nvm

I have got two node version installed using nvm.
When I am trying to switch to other I am getting below error

[image]

Looking at some solution, I added "Enabled" to the registry location

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings\Enabled`

but it did not fix it.
Also I tried running this in Administration access cmd window.